# Conditional Expectation for exponential distribution.

Tags: conditional-expectation, density-function

Let $Y$ have exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $X$ be such that, conditional on $Y=y, X$ has exponential distirbution with mean $y$.

I can see that this applies: $$E(X)=E[E(X|Y)]=E(Y)=\mu\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$$

How does $E[E(X|Y)]=E(Y)$ in this case?

Comment: Conditional on $Y=y$, $X$ is distributed exponential with mean $y$ so $E(X|Y=y)=y$, so $E(X|Y)(\omega)=Y(\omega)$. Now take the expectation again. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is the tower property of conditional expectation

Comment: @NapD.Lover - yes that does - thank you... I was going down a rabbit hole of joint density functions.